# Gitlab Jenkins Webhook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403 (Authentication required)

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

My WebHook was successful but jenkins does not build the project.

I checked the gitLab logs where it appears that the weebhook received a 200 response from jenkins

[Status 200 WebHook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FYTM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if this is similar to [jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issue 375](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/375#issuecomment-230685434):

> You can either add a special user in Jenkins for this and configure the Webhook in GitLab accordingly or
> you can uncheck the checkbox "Enable authentication for '/project' end-point" in the GitLab section of the global Jenkins configuration. But this should be unchecked by default.

Better, from [Jun Young Lee](https://github.com/legshort):

> You can set Secret Token as well and I think this method is better than two other options since no credential exposed or no too open policy.

[image: secret]

[image: using secret]

---

The [OP Alejandro Herrera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11116011/alejandro-herrera) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299209/gitlab-jenkins-webhook-executed-successfully-but-returned-http-403-authenticati/57301965?noredirect=1#comment101115681_57301965)

> I am using LDAP for authentication so it doesn't work with the token.
>
> But I already fixed it: I simply added the authentication parameters in the url like this: `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@Serverjenkins.com/github-webhook`

Comment: I am using LDAP for authentication so it doesn't work with the token, but I already fixed it.
I simply added the authentication parameters in the url like this: https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@Serverjenkins.com/github-webhook/

Comment: @AlejandroHerrera Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.